# Why delete event title and description in my Google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I connected google sheet to my calendar via [this sample spreadsheet connected to script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WNJyhhvyiQpDTXkASKzDj6OzIGfPaWWZ2Akanz7vDQ0/copy).

after import events from calendar to spreadsheet, titles and descriptions of imported events, deleted in calendar! But anything imported to spreadsheet keep original.
[image]

What is solution to back titles and description in my calendar?

---

- I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVHLgQ90zJo
- I Opened the link of the introduced solution: https://goo.gle/36EOhgF
- I Clicked on the "Make a Copy" button
- Set and run scripts

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] not a link to the script the code needs to be here in your question.

Comment: If the description is disappearing from the calendar event, my guess is that `exisitingEvent[descriptionColumn - 1]` is null when calling `event.setDescription(exisitingEvent[descriptionColumn - 1]);`. It's just a guess, though, since the linked code is very long and I didn't go through it all. In order to clarify this, please consider providing a minimal reproducible example, as already suggested by others.